# Cleaner way to throw exception if unable to get return value from Try execution

Tags: scala, exception, try-catch

A common meme I see when using Scala's wonderful `Try` construct is:

```
Try(canThrowException) match {
  case Success(result) => result
  case Failure(e) => throw new Exception("Couldn't do it", e)
}
```

I am often tempted to make this construct a bit more elegant:

```
Try(canThrowException).getOrElse(throw new Exception("Couldn't do it"))
```

Doing so removes my ability to chain the exception that was thrown by `canThrowException`, but looks prettier.

Do you know of a way to have both the elegant construct and the exception chaining?

Comment: You could add extension methods; `def throw(): Success[A]`, `def getOrThrow: A`, `def throw(f: Throwable => Nothing): Success[A]`, `def getOrThrow(f: Throwable => Nothing): A` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Generally it's probably better to recoverWith (and stay in Try) rather than actually throw:

```
val t = Try(canThrowException)

t recoverWith {
  case (e: Throwable) => { Failure(new Exception("Couldn't do it", e)) }
}
```

Comment: Neither of your examples retain the exception chaining. The first example can be chained trivially since `e` is already in scope, but I'm not entirely sure how one would chain the exception in your second example, if it is even possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`recover[U >: T](f: PartialFunction[Throwable, U]): Try[U]`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.util.Try@recover[U%3E:T](f:PartialFunction[Throwable,U]):scala.util.Try[U]):

```
Try(canThrowException) recover {
  case NonFatal(e) => throw new Exception("Couldn't do it", e)
} get
```

The `get` part is ugly indeed, but given that you've just handled all the reasonable exceptions, you only have the unreasonable (and re-thrown) ones left.